# How to test a privately-scoped or anonymous function?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testdoublejs

Imagine I have the following modules:

foo.js

```js
module.exports = function (x, f) {
  f(x);
};
```

bar.js

```js
const foo = require('./foo');

module.exports = function () {
  foo(40, n => n + 2);
  //      ^
  //      f — How can I test this lambda?
};
```

I only need to assert that when `bar` is called, `foo` is called exactly as shown above ^

I can test that `foo` has been called with `40` as follow:

```js
const td = require('testdouble');
const foo = td.replace('./foo');
const bar = require('./bar');

bar();

td.verify(foo(40, td.matchers.anything())); // Pass
```

But how can I verify that the function `f` is a function that takes a number, adds 2 to it and returns the result?

*PS: I am acutely aware that this isn't exactly testing best practices 101. I would rather not test in this way if I had the opportunity to do things differently. So please humor me.*

Answer (score 0):

I found two ways:

#### td.matchers.argThat

This matcher takes a predicate that takes the value of its positional parameter:

```js
const td = require('testdouble');
const foo = td.replace('./foo');
const bar = require('./bar');

bar();

td.verify(foo(40, td.matchers.argThat(f => f(40) === 42))); // Pass
```

#### td.matchers.captor

There is a special matcher called a [captor](http://testdouble.github.io/testdouble.js/6-verifying-invocations.html#multi-phase-assertions-with-argument-captors) that captures its positional parameter and makes it available later on via the `.value` property of the matcher:

```js
const tap = require('tap');
const td = require('testdouble');
const foo = td.replace('./foo');
const bar = require('./bar');
const f = td.matchers.captor();

bar();

td.verify(foo(40, f.capture()));

tap.equal(f.value(40), 42); // Pass
tap.equal(f.value(50), 52); // Pass
tap.equal(f.value(60), 62); // Pass
```